# List of files and folders that don't require authentication

Tags: dropbox-api

How can I get a list of shared files or folders that don't require you to authenticate to download the file etc, is there a specific attribute for the listed files and folders using "files_list_folder"

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a property on the entries returned by `files_list_folder`/`files_list_folder_continue` directly, but you can use [`files_get_temporary_link`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_get_temporary_link) to get a temporary direct link to a file. The `files_get_temporary_link` call itself requires authorization, but the resulting link doesn't.

Comment: I mean I want to retrieve a list of all Dropbox files inside a folder that don't require authorization to read or download (open files I mean) is there a way to retrieve such a list?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Files in Dropbox aren't "open". Dropbox offers a few different sharing mechanisms though. Are you referring to files that are available by some specific sharing mechanism? If so, please specify which.